# Using Magick++ in a node.js application on heroku

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, npm, node-gyp, magick++

I'm trying to push a Node app to heroku, but I am using [imagemagick-native](https://github.com/mash/node-imagemagick-native) and it seems that Heroku is having an issue with Magick++ - I've tried using custom build packs but can't seem to find one that supports Magick++.  (1) Is this the issue (2) Is there any solution to run Magick++ on Heorku?

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.10.20
       Using npm version: 1.3.11
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       npm WARN package.json upload@0.1.3 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
       npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field

       > bson@0.2.2 install /tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
       > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
         CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bson.node
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bson.node: Finished
         COPY Release/bson.node
       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'

       > kerberos@0.0.3 install /tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
       > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

       make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node
         SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node: Finished
         COPY Release/kerberos.node
       make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'

       > imagemagick-native@0.2.8 install /tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/imagemagick-native
       > node-gyp rebuild

       /bin/sh: Magick++-config: not found
       gyp: Call to 'Magick++-config --ldflags --libs' returned exit status 127. while trying to load binding.gyp
       gyp ERR! configure error
       gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/node-npm-k25M/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:424:16)
       gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
       gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
       gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
       gyp ERR! command "node" "/tmp/node-npm-k25M/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
       gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_d2a98573-34b8-42d9-91ff-81c4ca84feb9/node_modules/imagemagick-native
       gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.20
       gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
       gyp ERR! not ok
       npm ERR! weird error 1
       npm ERR! not ok code 0
 !     Failed to rebuild dependencies with npm

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress on this:

Use the [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi):

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

So that it can load the [apt-buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) in addition to the nodejs one. List your builpacks in `.buildpacks`:

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
```

Now install `libmagick++-dev` through apt by listing it in a file called `Aptfile`.

Now if you include imagemagick-native in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "imagemagick-native": "1.7.0"
}
```

It will start compiling. And although `$CPATH` is set properly by the APT package, `node-gyp` somehow doesn't seem to forward it to gcc.

This causes the following error:

```
remote:        > imagemagick-native@1.7.0 install /tmp/build_720834c3a32b65d69ae603d7c618e20f/node_modules/imagemagick-native
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_720834c3a32b65d69ae603d7c618e20f/node_modules/imagemagick-native/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/imagemagick/src/imagemagick.o
remote:        In file included from ../src/imagemagick.cc:9:
remote:        ../src/imagemagick.h:1:22: warning: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
```

So it doesn't solve the problem yet, but I think it's on the right track. Still trying to figure out what's up with node-gyp.

---

#### Update

To workaround that problem fork the nodejs buildpack and add the following lines to the top of `bin/compile`:

```
path=`echo "$INCLUDE_PATH" | cut -d : -f 1`
export CXX="`which g++` -I$path/ImageMagick"
```

Works on `cedar-14`. For the deprecated `cedar` you would need to use imagemagick-native v1.22.