# Add include dir for node gyp

Tags: node.js, gcc, npm, node-gyp, gyp

I am deploying a node-js app to heroku that requires the npm package [imagemagic-native](https://github.com/mash/node-imagemagick-native).

I made the buildpack install `libmagick++-dev` and export the include path:

```
export INCLUDE_PATH="$BUILD_DIR/.apt/usr/include:$INCLUDE_PATH"
export CPATH="$INCLUDE_PATH"
export CPPPATH="$INCLUDE_PATH"
```

Upon installing the `imagemagic-native` package with `npm install`, node-gyp is invoked to compile it's binaries. However I get this error:

```
remote:        > imagemagick-native@1.7.0 install /tmp/build_720834c3a32b65d69ae603d7c618e20f/node_modules/imagemagick-native
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_720834c3a32b65d69ae603d7c618e20f/node_modules/imagemagick-native/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/imagemagick/src/imagemagick.o
remote:        In file included from ../src/imagemagick.cc:9:
remote:        ../src/imagemagick.h:1:22: warning: Magick++.h: No such file or directory
```

This suggests that gcc doesn't see the header files for `libmagick++`, because `$CCPATH` is not available to it.

How can I make `npm install` add the path to the list of `include_dirs` that node-gyp uses?

More detail about my use case is here: [Using Magick++ in a node.js application on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19612789/1238764)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

setting the environment variable CXX=/path/to/g++ -Ipath/to/include

and then restarting the process. If you're using bash this is done by

```
export CXX="/path/to/g++ -Ipath/to/include"
```

/path/to/include being where the missing header Magick++.h is located

if that doesn't work you may manually have to set CXX to include the -I in the makefile at /tmp/build_720834c3a32b65d69ae603d7c618e20f/node_modules/imagemagick-native/build then cding into that directory and calling make.

Comment: That export worked! Thank you very much. The latter was not an option as its a fully automated build.

Comment: The latter is always an option, unlike the former, if you know enough.

Answer (score 7):

I've spent some time trying to answer the same question. In the end, i've found the proper way to do this [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp/+/master/docs/UserDocumentation.md). You need to set `'include_dirs'` property in `~/.node-gyp/x.x.x/common.gypi`.
This is how I've set the include dir on Mac OS to `/opt/local/include/` (which is where all macports intalls go):

```
...
['OS=="mac"', {
  'defines': ['_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1'],
  'include_dirs': ['/opt/local/include'],
  'xcode_settings': {
    'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS': 'NO',
...
```

Though I'm not sure it's applicable for heroku environment.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. For me, on OX 10.11.5 the common.gypi was in ~/.node-gyp/x.x.x/include/node .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "include_dirs" option in your project binding.gyp file. Read more about available options on the [format description page](https://gyp.gsrc.io/docs/InputFormatReference.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can now do `OTHER_CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/include'` supposedly. See https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-nanomsg/pull/144